# How to re-initialize a lazy property from another view?

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-loading, computed-properties

I have data that I want to read from disk into memory that takes a nontrivial amount of time.
I want to be able to do two things:

1. I don't the data to be read every time the view loads.
2. I want to be able to invoke it from another view.

```swift
lazy var data: [String: String] = {
    guard let data = readFromDisk() else { return [:] }
    return processData(data: data)
}()
```

Above code gets initialized only once when the view loads for the first time, which is perfect for eliminating unnecessary computation. The problem is I also want to be able to trigger it from another view when needed.

I tried to trigger re-initialization:

```swift
func getData() {
    guard let data = readFromDisk() else { return [:] }
    data = processData(data: data)
}
```

and invoke it from another view:

```swift
let vc = ViewController()
vc.getData()
```

but, doesn't work.
I tried to see if I could use `static` since it's also `lazy`, but I get an error saying:

> Instance member cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Finally, I tried creating a separate class:

```swift
class DataImporter {
    var data: [String: String] {
        guard let data = readFromDisk() else { return [:] }
        return processData(data: data)
    }
    
    func readFromDisk() -> [String: String] {}
    func processData(data: [String: String]) -> [String: String] {}
}
```

and have the lazy property in `ViewController`:

```swift
lazy var importer = DataImporter()
```

thinking that instantiating a class achieves the dual effect of taking advantage of a lazy property and invoking it when needed:

```swift
let vc = ViewController()
vc.importer = DataImporter()
```

This instantiates the class about a hundred times for some reason which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a function that loads the data into `data` and then whenever you need to reload `data`, simply reassign it.

```
class DataStore {
    lazy var data: [String: String] = loadData()

    func readFromDisk() -> Data? {...}

    func processData(data: Data) -> [String:String] { ... }

    func loadData() -> [String:String] {
        guard let data = readFromDisk() else { return [:] }
        return processData(data: data)
    }
}

let store = DataStore()
let data = store.data // only loaded here
store.data = store.loadData() // reloads the data
```

If you don't want the `loadData` function to be exposed, you can also create a separate `reloadData` function.

```
class DataStore {
    ...
    func reloadData() {
        data = loadData()
    }
}
```

and then instead of doing `store.data = store.loadData()`, simply call `store.reloadData()`